# Subdomain NameServers to control fourth level domains using Route53?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, subdomain, nameserver, amazon-route53

We have external service that we have no control of, and it is on client side. But we need some subdomains and flexibility there, and process of making them to do work - is huge pain.

So we need subdomain:

```
api.example.com
```

We host everything on AWS and use Elastic IP, and are happy to use Route53.
What we want, is to be able to point *api.example.com* to **Route53 Name Servers** and then manage all records and subsubdomains our self.
Like change **A Record** for *api.example.com*.
And be able to add more subsubdomains like:

```
media.api.example.com
```

And be able to point them the way we want.

So what the solution to such task?
**If NS record to Route 53 for *api.example.com* by the other guys, will grand full control for us? Or we still wont be able to manage subsubdomains?**

UPD (after tests):
**It does work as a charm.** Based on Domain Zones it will use closest branch with NS record to resolve the routing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is no different than making any other zone work. Add NS records pointing to the nameservers that are authorative over api.example.com in the example.com zone.

The A record works the same way, simply add it in the appropriate zone.

Comment: So it means any lower level records of api.example.com will be managed by that pointed NameServer rather than first level one? Right?

Comment: A NS record specifies a nameserver that is authorative over a zone. Any records part of that zone are by definition managed by its nameservers.

Comment: Thank you for helping out, just verified that it works as a charm. But the only problem here I can see, is that not every Domain Management services allow to change NS Record for subdomains.

Comment: I suggest using a service that doesn't suck then :)